# ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE in oracle or equiv (defining key/column?)

Tags: php, sql, oracle, sql-update, sql-insert

I have the below working `insert` statement, where I am essentially mapping the column data from an uploaded *.csv* file through a loop into my `VALUES` variables below...

All worked fine, except now I am just trying to add a tweak `INSERT` or `UPDATE` - if '`app_id`' first *column*, value is found in the uploaded .csv, *i.e.* duplicate is found - simply update the identified duplicate row..

Based on some research `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` is the way to go, but **I don't understand how/where I define the key?** - you can see below I tried adding the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` to the end of the query with my variables again, but I'm pretty sure this can't be correct.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO app.also_data (app_id, fac_ident, lg_name, basic_tp, catc_vd, address, assoc_city, latitude, longitude, assoc_cnty, assoc_st, time_zone, dd_reg, ato_sa, ato_td, fema_reg, ops_hrs, prim_ph, atc_level, tower_type, manager, sat_phone_num, td_mgr, to_dist, tod_mgr, stof_fac, ops_status, crt_rl, created_user, date)
                      VALUES ('${data[0]}', '${data[1]}', '${data[2]}', '${data[3]}', '${data[4]}', '${data[5]}', '${data[6]}', '${data[7]}', '${data[8]}', '${data[9]}', '${data[10]}', '${data[11]}', '${data[12]}', '${data[13]}', '${data[14]}', '${data[15]}', '${data[16]}', '${data[17]}', '${data[18]}', '${data[19]}', '${data[20]}', '${data[21]}', '${data[22]}', '${data[23]}', '${data[24]}', '${data[25]}', '${data[26]}', '${data[27]}', '${data[28]}', '${data[29]}') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ('${data[0]}', '${data[1]}', '${data[2]}', '${data[3]}', '${data[4]}', '${data[5]}', '${data[6]}', '${data[7]}', '${data[8]}', '${data[9]}', '${data[10]}', '${data[11]}', '${data[12]}', '${data[13]}', '${data[14]}', '${data[15]}', '${data[16]}', '${data[17]}', '${data[18]}', '${data[19]}', '${data[20]}', '${data[21]}', '${data[22]}', '${data[23]}', '${data[24]}', '${data[25]}', '${data[26]}', '${data[27]}', '${data[28]}', '${data[29]}')";
```

Note: The above was working fine for Insert minus my below attempt adding:

```
... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ('${data[0]}', '${data[1]}', '${data[2]}', '${data[3]}', '${data[4]}', '${data[5]}', '${data[6]}', '${data[7]}', '${data[8]}', '${data[9]}', '${data[10]}', '${data[11]}', '${data[12]}', '${data[13]}', '${data[14]}', '${data[15]}', '${data[16]}', '${data[17]}', '${data[18]}', '${data[19]}', '${data[20]}', '${data[21]}', '${data[22]}', '${data[23]}', '${data[24]}', '${data[25]}', '${data[26]}', '${data[27]}', '${data[28]}', '${data[29]}')";
```

So how can I add `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` based off of column `app_id` correctly - if duplicate `app_id` value is found in the `insert`, simply `update` instead?

Comment: `ON DUPLICATE KEY` is a MySQL extension, it does not exist in Oracle. Are you running Oracle or MySQL?

Comment: I am running oracle... Is there an oracle equivalent?

Comment: I see it in the oracle docs? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-5.6-en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ON DUPLICATE KEY` is not a thing in Oracle. The closest equivalent is the `MERGE` syntax. Here is an example on how to use it for your use case (I reduced the number of columns for the sake of readability):

```
merge into app.also_data a
using (select ? app_id, ? fac_ident, ? lg_name, ? basic_tp from dual) p
on (a.app_id = p.app_id)
when matched then 
    update set 
        a.fac_ident = p.fac_ident, 
        a.lg_name = p.lg_name, 
        a.basic_tp = p.basic_tp
when not matched then 
    insert(app_id, fac_ident, lg_name, basic_tp) 
    values(p.app_id, p.fac_ident, p.lg_name, p.basic_tp)
```